# New to Ubunutu, problem installing VMware

Tags: command-line, software-installation, vmware

I want to be able to run Windows 7 right off the windows OS. I installed the VMware workstation pro 12 64 bit (from http://www.vmware.com/products/works...ion-evaluation), and then tried both of these commands in the terminal:

```
$ chmod +x VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle
$ sh VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle
```

for the `chmod` command I get back:

```
cannot access 'blahblahblah.bundle': No such file or directory
```

and for the `sh` command I get:

```
sh: 0: Can't open blahblablah.bundle
```

Any pointers, or leads on where to look? I am literally just beginning with linux, financial necessity is throwing this challenge my way (I need the windows for work).

Also, what is the difference between VMware workstation and player?

Comment: Could you please execute this command and add output to your question: `ls -ahl ~/Downloads/VMware*`

Comment: I've tried executing the command, just getting back 1s: command not found. I put it in as:

    `1s  -ah1 ~/Downloads/VMware*`

Comment: in `ls` first symbol is lowercase `L`, not 1 (one)

Comment: Ah I thought I must be making a mistake like that. Okay, I entered it correctly and:

`/home/icarus/Downloads/VMware-Workstation-Full-12.0.0-2985596.x85_64.bundle`

So is ls a command for locating files?

Comment: `ls` is for listing directory, to showing what is inside directory. Most everything that is downloaded in Linux from web browser could be located in `~/Downloads` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this commands to start installation of VMWare:

```
$ chmod +x /home/icarus/Downloads/VMware-Workstation-Full-12.0.0-2985596.x85_64.bundle
$ sh /home/icarus/Downloads/VMware-Workstation-Full-12.0.0-2985596.x85_64.bundle
```

---

Answering you question in comment: `ls` is

```
DESCRIPTION
       List  information  about  the FILEs (the current directory by default).
       Sort entries alphabetically if none of -cftuvSUX nor --sort  is  speci‐
       fied.
```

If you want to know more about some commands use manuals. To access manuals use `man` command. For example `man ls` or `man chmod`. To exit from man pages press `q`.

Comment: Same result as before, check it out:
`icarus@EyeZaPryze:~$ chmod +x /home/icarus/Downloads/VMware-Workstation-Full-12.0.0-2985596.x85_64.bundle
chmod: cannot access ‘/home/icarus/Downloads/VMware-Workstation-Full-12.0.0-2985596.x85_64.bundle’: No such file or directory
icarus@EyeZaPryze:~$ ls -ah1 ~/Downloads/VMware*
/home/icarus/Downloads/VMware-Workstation-Full-12.0.0-2985596.x86_64.bundle
icarus@EyeZaPryze:~$ sh /home/icarus/Downloads/VMWare-Workstation-Full-12.0.0-2985596.x86_64.bundle
sh: 0: Can't open /home/icarus/Downloads/VMWare-Workstation-Full-12.0.0-2985596.x86_64.bundle`